# iOS9 positioning bug, calculates position differently

Tags: html, css, ios9

I'm trying to figure out why iOS9 positions my mobile menu button 7px lower than every other system/browser in the world.

I don't know how to cleanly extrapolate this into a fiddle, but the bug is on iedm.com menu button on iphone or ipad iOS9 safari or chrome.

At first the iOS9 upgrade caused it to disappear completely, then after some troubleshooting and experimenting with it for an hour I've got it showing now but for some reason it's 7px lower than any other device (causing to become non-centered).

I'm asking if anyone knows what I can look for to debug, or any css rules or hacks specific to iOS9 that would cause the positioning to function differently.

Such an ambigous bug... thanks for any help.

Comment: I think that's not a bug, but you don't share any code or how do you define the CSS (position and measures) and the javascript (function to read what is the position). I can show you a simple CSS to center vertical or horizontal with CSS in every system with 100% fidelity. Tell me something.

Comment: If you have a Mac, you can connect the iPhone to Safari desktop and inspect the code. You could just create a media query that lifts the button higher on small, high-resolution devices. But I'd be looking at a better positioning method to start with. There are better options available.

Comment: thanks ralph going to try connecting the device and inspect the codee. media query won't work because it's ios9 specific, not device.

Comment: Maybe your devide is a 2 or 3 pixel-ratio, and the pixels doesn't have the same size than a normal screen. I insist in that you need to share the code if you need help from us. If the question was "how to debug iOS website" is different than "iOS9 positioning bug". Do you understand me?